# How does "__builtin_popcount" of gcc work?

Tags: c++, gcc

I want know the inner workings of "__builtin_popcount".

As much as I understand, it works differently for different cpu.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to many other built-ins, it translates into specific CPU instruction if one is available on the target CPU, thus considerably speeding up the application.

For example, on x86_64 it translates to `popcntl` ASM instruction.

Additional information can be found on GCC page: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

It is also worth noting that the actual speedup could only be seen if gcc is ran with `march` flag which targets architecture supporting this instruction or an argument which specifically enables it, `-mpopcnt`. Without either of those, gcc will revert to generic bit counting via bit operations.